# QT .pro file: How to change default include path for MAC frameworks

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, moc, qt5.5

My `.pro` file looks like this:

```
QT += core gui widgets 

SOURCES += a.cpp    
HEADERS  += a.h
FORMS   += a.ui

#Locally compiled Qt framework. Qt/out/{QtCore.framework,QtNetwork.framework..}
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -L./Qt/lib/
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F./Qt/lib/


macx {
    QMAKE_MAC_SDK   = macosx10.9
    LIBS            += -framework QtCore -framework QtNetwork -framework QtGui -framework QtWidgets
}
```

I want to use frameworks compiled locally, but QT5.5 automatically includes framework from QT5.5.0 install directory ... I see a.cpp compiling with following include switch:

```
 -I/Users/banana/Qt5.5.0/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers
```

I tried resetting `INCLUDEPATH =` in `.pro` file in hopes that it resets the default include path and added proper `INCLUDEPATH += ./Qt/lib` but it doesn't work.

Using MAC, OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Are you running qmake from your locally compiled Qt framework?

Comment: No from QT tools install dir. QT tools install directory ( ~/Qt5.5/ ), QT source framework (~/qt-everywhere-5.5) and QT application is in (~/qt-app/).

Comment: IIRC qmake is configured to use a particular Qt install. If you run the qmake that was compiled with your local framework, it should generate include references to your local framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt installation that gets used will be determined by which `qmake` you run. If you have multiple versions of Qt installed (e.g. one you built from sources yourself and one provided by the system or by a Qt Creator install), you need to ensure you are running the `qmake` from the Qt you want to use. You should be able to verify this from the command line fairly easily. If you are using an IDE like Qt Creator and are having issues getting the right Qt selected, try building from a command line first to verify that you can get the right Qt that way as a first step. If building things from the command line where you have absolute control over which `qmake` is used still doesn't work, then this would suggest the `qmake` you are trying to use isn't behaving in the expected way.

Comment: For Qt Creator: Preferences->Build&Run->Qt Versions click "add...", then navigate to the Qt compiled sources's "bin" folder and pick the qmake there. This will create a new Qt Version you can choose for building your code. Select it in "Kits" tab on the "Build&Run" page.

Comment: I used `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/src/qtbase/bin/qmake` and I didn't have to change `.pro` file at all