# Qt5.5.1: How to create QT application that uses frameworks generated from qt-everywhere-opensource-src

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake, moc, qt5.5

I should have asked this question before asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578619/qt-pro-file-how-to-change-default-include-path-for-mac-frameworks?noredirect=1#comment54935455_33578619)

I am creating a QT app (on MAC) that should use frameworks compiled from qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.tgz and not the one that comes with qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.5.0.dmg.

I use QT creator installed by that DMG file and qmake in it somehow links with the frameworks installed by this DMG. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578619/qt-pro-file-how-to-change-default-include-path-for-mac-frameworks?noredirect=1#comment54935455_33578619) for more details)

Whats the legit way of making this QT creator use other framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Creator has the concept of build *Kits*. A kit includes (among other things) a compiler, debugger and Qt version. In the Qt Creator preferences, go to the *Build & Run* section. Under the *Qt Versions* tab, ensure that your Qt 5.5.1 built from source is listed there. Then go to the *Kits* tab and either create a new kit or modify an existing one. Ensure that kit is using your Qt 5.5.1 version.

Once you've got that sorted out, a project can have one or more kits associated with it. From the main window, go to the *Projects* panel. Near the top of the *Build & Run* tab of the projects page will be the section where you select the kit(s) for the project. Ensure your project is using the kit you created/modified which uses your Qt 5.5.1. That should be enough to get your project building with your version of Qt instead of the one that comes with Qt Creator. To be absolutely sure, perhaps delete any previous build before you switch kits or even better, create a new build configuration in a new build/output directory for it.